# UWP - AutoSuggestBox customization

Tags: validation, xaml, templates, uwp, autosuggest

I need to support validation on some standard AutoSuggestBox control. So my idea was to customize AutoSuggestBox control by changing it's TextBox to ValidatingTextBox (my implementation of ValidatingTextBox by James Croft). Is that even possible? If yes - how, and if not - what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

> So my idea was to customize AutoSuggestBox control by changing it's TextBox to ValidatingTextBox

It is not recommended replacing the `TextBox` of `AutoSuggestBox`. Some default functionalities might fail because of that. Instead, you can add some function to it. And [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) offers a great validation extension to `TextBox` control.

You can apply this extension to `AutoSuggestBox` by following steps:

1. Reference WinRTXamlToolkit in your project. Add reference of `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions` in your XAML page like below:

   ```
   <Page
   ...
   xmlns:extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions"
   ...>
   ```
2. Create a copy of your `AutoSuggestBox` control's style template with Visual Studio. Or you can copy the template from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and apply it to your AutoSuggestBox control.
3. Find the TextBox Control in the template. Add `extensions:FieldValidationExtensions.Format="the format you need"` to it like below:

   ```
   <TextBox extensions:FieldValidationExtensions.Format="Numeric"
            x:Name="TextBox" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
   ```
4. If you want to show validation error message. You can change the panel of this `TextBox` from `Grid` to `StackPanel` and add a `TextBlock` like below:

   ```
   <StackPanel>
         <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                   <VisualState x:Name="Landscape"/>
                   <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
                   </VisualStateGroup>
               </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
               <TextBox extensions:FieldValidationExtensions.Format="Numeric"
                           x:Name="TextBox" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
               <TextBlock  Text="{Binding (extensions:FieldValidationExtensions.ValidationMessage), ElementName=TextBox}"
                           Visibility="{Binding (extensions:FieldValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageVisibility), ElementName=TextBox}" />
            ...
   </StackPanel>
   ```

Now you get a basic validatingAutoSuggestBox ready for use.

Comment: Sorry for not answering. This method didn't work for me so I used combination of ASB and ValidatingTB and modifying style. They are bind to the same property and everything works like it should.